# Use one textfield for searching in two or more fields in Views

Tags: 7, views

I have a simple content type in Drupal 7 with title and body (and other fields). I've defined a view with exposed filters.

I want just one text field that searches in title or body. So, if I search for 'foo' both nodes with 'foo' in their body or/and title will be matched.

One solution is to use "Global: Combine fields filter" and combine title and body, but Views then uses a CONCAT function in where clausule, something bad for performance.

I've a solution, but there're drawbacks and I'm not sure if it's optimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Vies or/and funcionality I set (using more fields not related to this question):

filed1 AND
 field2 AND
 ...
 fieldN 
AND
 title OR
 body

title is not expsed, but body is.

My solution is to implement hook_views_pre_build(&$view).

```
if ($view->name == 'my-view') {
  // Look for the search string, is it present?
  if (!empty($_GET['search'])) {
    $view->filter['title']->value = check_plain($_GET['search']);
  }
}
```

I've renamed body key in GET to be search.

This way search is performed as I want. The drawback is I can't position search element anywhere becasue it must be in its own group, but I can live with it.